# C++ OpenGL flickering Issues

Tags: c++, opengl, flicker

Im having a Problem, where when I just render 1 Cube it's all okay, but if I add multiple Cubes all of them start flickering.. might be because they are intefering each other but im using double dubbers so it shouldn't be that. here the code of the render method

```
for (std::vector<Entity *>::iterator iterator = entityArray->begin(); iterator != entityArray->end(); iterator++) {

    Entity *entity = *iterator;
    if (entity->getVertexBuffer() != NULL) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShader()->getProgramHandle());

        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(_currentCamera->getPosition().x,
            _currentCamera->getPosition().y,
            _currentCamera->getPosition().z,
            _currentCamera->getEyeVector().x,
            _currentCamera->getEyeVector().y,
            _currentCamera->getEyeVector().z,
            _currentCamera->getUpVector().x,
            _currentCamera->getUpVector().y,
            _currentCamera->getUpVector().z);

        glTranslatef(entity->getPosition().x, entity->getPosition().y, entity->getPosition().z);

        glRotatef(entity->getRotation().x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glRotatef(entity->getRotation().y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(entity->getRotation().z, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glScalef(entity->getScale().x, entity->getScale().y, entity->getScale().z);

        glUniform4f(entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShader()->get_uColor(),
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uColorValue().x,
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uColorValue().y,
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uColorValue().z,
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uColorValue().w);

        glUniform3f(entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShader()->get_uLightPosition(),
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uLightPosition().x,
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uLightPosition().y,
            entity->getVertexBuffer()->getShaderData()->get_uLightPosition().z);


        entity->getVertexBuffer()->configureVertexAttributes();
        entity->getVertexBuffer()->renderVertexBuffer();

        glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear first, draw all cubes, then swap, like this:

```
glClear();

for (cube in cubes) { draw(cube); }

glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

That should solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling glClear and glSwapBuffers in the inner loop. So for everything you draw in the inner loop, it clears the picture, draws the thing (a single cube) swaps and then does the same for the next element in the array.

Everything that does not draw a cube must go outside of that loop.

Comment: If I do it outside of the Loop it doesn't flicker anymore but it only shows one Cube..

Comment: @user3718162: Well, you don't gave us your shader code (you're using uniforms and the fixed function matrices in the same program, which is weird – don't do that). Also when only one cube shows up, make sure you actually draw the other cubes. `renderVertexBuffer` will probably contain calls to `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` – those must go into the loop, of course.